# What is the difference between rocket::ignite() and rocket::build()?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm learning rocket framework and I came a cross with method after you launch the application.

```
#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index])
}
```

or without attribute "launch"

```
fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .launch();
}
```

Comment: Without in-depth research, I think `::ignite()` is `v0.4`, while `::build()` is `v0.5`. Rocket went through a major rewrite for `v0.5`, reimplementing everything with `async`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, [`rocket::ignite()`](https://docs.rs/rocket/latest/rocket/fn.ignite.html) from version 0.4 is pretty much identical to [`rocket::build()`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/fn.build.html) from version 0.5. They both load the configuration (see [0.4 guide](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/configuration/) and [0.5 guide](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/configuration/)) and create the `Rocket` isntance in a state for you to `.mount()` routes, `.manage()` state, `.attach()` fairings, and other such customizations.

The big difference with initialization in version 0.5 is the `Rocket` type now uses a typestate pattern to encode the different "[phases](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/struct.Rocket.html#phases)" that an application instance can be in:

> - `Rocket<Build>`: This is the only phase in which an instance can be modified. To finalize changes, an instance is ignited via `Rocket::ignite()`, progressing it into the ignite phase, or directly launched into orbit with `Rocket::launch()` which progress the instance through ignite into orbit.
> - `Rocket<Ignite>`: An instance in the `Ignite` phase is in its final configuration, available via `Rocket::config()`. Barring user-supplied interior mutation, application state is guaranteed to remain unchanged beyond this point. An instance in the ignite phase can be launched into orbit to serve requests via `Rocket::launch()`.
> - `Rocket<Orbit>`: An instance in the `Orbit` phase represents a running application, actively serving requests.

The wording did change since "ignition" used to happen before configuration but now it happens after (which makes more sense to me). The general flow of creating a Rocket server is no different, just the typestate pattern helps enforce consistency and expectations. You generally don't see the other states like `Rocket<Orbit>`, except if you use a [`Fairing`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/fairing/trait.Fairing.html).

---

The [`#[launch]`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/attr.launch.html) attribute is new in 0.5 and does a number of things. Crucially it starts an `async` runtime since Rocket is 100% asynchronous as of 0.5. It also creates your `main()` function, if you didn't want that then you can use the `#[rocket::main]` attribute on your own `main()` instead. Then it then calls `.launch()` on your `Rocket<Build>` instance and `.await`s the result; in other words, it starts the server.